# How to test the value returned from of a hash table access

Tags: perl

I am iterating an hash table and i retrieve the value using the key as an access. I want to test the accessed value to see if it matches a particular string however i am not getting any print statement in the if condition that tests if the value is a particular string.

Assume i have a hash table called margin_hash which contains Key
and value pairs where the key is a margin name and the value is 
a string.

```
foreach my $margin_name (keys %margin_hash) {
    my $type = $margin_hash{$margin_name}{"MARGIN TYPE"};
    if ( $type eq "DELAY") {
      print "FOUND a DELAY margin\n";
    }
}
```

I know my hash table contains a value "DELAY". However it seems
the if condition is somehow not working?

I expected output to print FOUND a DELAY margin

Comment: If your if statement is not succeeding, then your hash table does not contain the value 'DELAY'. Perhaps the value you set was not exactly 'DELAY', such as if it still contained a trailing newline when read from something else.

Comment: Add this before `if` to find the actual hash value, since it probably contains other something else (leading/trailing whitespace, other characters): `print qq{"$margin_name" => "$type"\n};`

Comment: I've added indentation to your code to make it easier to follow. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing that yourself in the future.

Comment: What do you see if you add to your code: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%margin_hash;`?

Answer (score 4):

`$type eq "DELAY"` checks of the value of `$type` is a string that is identical to `DELAY`, (or something that stringifies to such a string).

`$type =~ "DELAY"` (a weird way of writing `$type =~ /DELAY/`) checks if the value of `$type` matches regex pattern `DELAY`. If will match if the value is a string that *contains* `DELAY` (or something that stringifies to such a string).

Since `$type =~ "DELAY"` is true and `$type eq "DELAY"` is false, you have a string that isn't `DELAY`, but contains `DELAY`. Maybe you have a trailing line feed? [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) lines you read from files.